# MS Access - Pass-through value from two Forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, pass-through

Background:

I have three forms for generating a new request, and here's why:

Form 1: frmRequests - Create New Request (Data is tblRequests)
Everything works here, fine - the buttons are:

Button 1 - Save and Exit - Adds the new request to the tblRequests table with status of 'Pending'

Button 2 - Save and Finish Later - Does the same as above with status of 'Incomplete'

Form 2: frmIncRequest - Edit Existing Request (Data is qryIncReq - which filters only on Status = "Incomplete") so they can continue the request.  I have other code that opens the form to a select project number from a combo box on the Main Menu.

Form 2 is basically a copy of Form 1, but the Data Source is different.
Form 2 is opened based on a selection from a combo box using the qryIncReq query

Each of those forms has an option for Multiple Requests if there are other work orders related to one project. A selection button opens the Multiple Requests form.

The Project Number field has to match the Project Number on Form 1 or Form 2 depending on which one is open at the time.

From 3: Multiple Requests:
On the Project Number field I have the following:
Property Sheet > Data tab > Default Value = [Forms]![frmRequests]![txtProjectNumber] and it works wonderfully, and if I change it to the frmIncRequest too.

My question is:
Is there a way to change this to look at the form depending on which one is open? or
Do I have to create another Multiple Requests form to finish the Incomplete Requests?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would make one form work for creating new record as well as editing existing and use VBA to apply filter when form opens or to move to new record row.

Comment: Are you suggesting adding a third form and use that as the pass through for the other three forms?

Comment: No, I am suggesting form 1 and form 2 (and possibly even form 3) be only 1 form. The RecordSource would not have to be changed. Code would apply filter to form as needed.